# test if the user has filled all the inputs in a form

Tags: php, javascript

I have a login form in my page and I want to test if the user has filled all the inputs, this is the code I tried but it won't work :

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var check {};

            check['login'] = function () {

                var login = document.getElementById('login');
                if(login.value.length > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            check['mdp'] = function () {

                var mdp = document.getElementById('mdp');
                if(login.value.length > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

            for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
            {
                inputs[i].onkeyup = function() {
                    check[this.id](this.id);
                }
            }

            var result = true;

            for (var i in check)
            {
                result = check[i](i) && result;
            }

            var myForm = document.getElementById('form1');

            if (!result)
            {
                alert('Vueillez saisir tous les champs !');
            }

            myForm.addEventListener('valider', function (e) {
                if (!result) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                }
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            require_once('bdd.inc.php');




            if (isset($_POST['valider'])) {

                $auth = false;

                foreach($clients as $client)
                {
                    if($_POST['login'] == $client['Pseudo'] && $_POST['mdp'] == $client['MotDePasse'])
                    {
                        $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
                        $_SESSION['mdp'] = $_POST['mdp'];
                        $auth = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(!$auth)
                {
                    header('location:authentification.php?auth=false');
                }
            }

        ?>
        <form method="post" action="authentification.php" id="form1" name="form1">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Login :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="login" id="login"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mot de passe :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mdp" id="mdp"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Valider" name="valider" id="valider"></td></tr>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['auth']))
                    {
                        if($_GET['auth'] == 'false')
                        {
                            echo '<div style="color:red">Désolé, Votre pseudo ou votre mot de passe est erroné !</div>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the problem is when I click in the submit button it redirects me to the action page in spite of the inputs are not filled

Comment: I don't know if javascript let u use fonction() instead of function()

Comment: This really has nothing to do with your PHP.

Comment: @Perroloco I've changed  fonction() to  function() I totally forgot about this because we are studying IT in french, But I still have the problem

Comment: @j08691 no it has, I added an event to the submit button `e.preventDefault();` which will prevent the submit button from it's default behavior so it won't redirects me to the action page if the test I made returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a browser will submit a button with `type="submit"` before a JavaScript scripe will finish executing.  What you want to do is have your script submit your form after it validates.  So change your input type to button, and do a submit from javascript itself.

EDIT: (per comment)

You already are submitting the form via JavaScript.  To get your code to work, I would simply change your input button from type submit to button. so change `<input type="submit" value="Valider" name="valider" id="valider">` to this:

```
<input type="button" value="Valider" name="valider" id="valider">
```

Comment: and how can I do the submit using the JS ?

Comment: Try changing <input type="button" value="Valider" name="valider" id="valider">

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('bdd.inc.php');
if (isset($_POST['valider'])) {

    $auth = false;

    foreach($clients as $client)
    {
        if($_POST['login'] == $client['Pseudo'] && $_POST['mdp'] == $client['MotDePasse'])
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
            $_SESSION['mdp'] = $_POST['mdp'];
            $auth = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$auth)
    {
        header('location:authentification.php?auth=false');
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validation(form)
            {
                var login = document.getElementById('login');
                var mdp = document.getElementById('mdp');
                if(login.value == '' || mdp.value == '')
                    alert('You must fill in all fields!');
                else
                    form.submit();

                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="authentification.php" id="form1" name="form1" onsubmit="validation(this);return false">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Login :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="login" id="login"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mot de passe :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mdp" id="mdp"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Valider" name="valider" id="valider"></td></tr>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['auth']))
                    {
                        if($_GET['auth'] == 'false')
                        {
                            echo '<div style="color:red">Désolé, Votre pseudo ou votre mot de passe est erroné !</div>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```