# When Adding header code ignores the validation conditions

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this form which register new clients and I have made a validation conditions to each filed of the form... everything gos OK unless if I try to redirect the user the another page
it ignores the validations conditions and pass the form

See the code

```
$FirstUniversityDegree = $university = $otherUniversity = $faculty = $otherFaculty = $major = $otherMajor
    = $univGrad = $gradProject = $graduationYear = $highSchool = $schoolGrad = $highestUnivDegree = $otherHighEdu
    = $research = $educationYear = $educationGrad = $lang1 = $lang1degree = $lang2 = $lang2degree = $lang3 = $lang3degree
    = $lang4 = "";

$FirstUniversityDegreeErr = $universityErr = $otherUniversityErr = $facultyErr = $otherFacultyErr = $majorErr
    = $otherMajorErr = $univGradErr = $gradProjectErr = $graduationYearErr = $highSchoolErr = $schoolGradErr
    = $highestUnivDegreeErr = $otherHighEduErr = $researchErr = $educationYearErr = $educationGradErr = $lang1Err
    = $lang1degreeErr = $lang2Err = $lang2degreeErr = $lang3Err = $lang3degreeErr = $lang4Err = "";

$id = "";
$uid = "";

if (isset($_POST['subEducation'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['FirstUniversityDegree'])) {
        $FirstUniversityDegreeErr = "First University Degree Required";
    } else {
        $FirstUniversityDegree = check_input($_POST['FirstUniversityDegree']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['university'])) {
        $universityErr = "University Required";
    } else {
        $university = check_input($_POST['university']);
    }

    $otherUniversity = check_input($_POST['otherUniversity']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $otherUniversity)) {
        $otherUniversityErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['faculty'])) {
        $facultyErr = "Faculty Required";
    } else {
        $faculty = check_input($_POST['faculty']);
    }

    $otherFaculty = check_input($_POST['otherFaculty']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $otherFaculty)) {
        $otherFacultyErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['major'])) {
        $majorErr = "Major Required";
    } else {
        $major = check_input($_POST['major']);
    }

    $otherMajor = check_input($_POST['otherMajor']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $otherMajor)) {
        $otherMajorErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['univGrad'])) {
        $univGradErr = "Grade Required";
    } else {
        $univGrad = check_input($_POST['univGrad']);
    }

    $gradProject = check_input($_POST['gradProject']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $gradProject)) {
        $gradProjectErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $graduationYear = check_input($_POST['graduationYear']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $graduationYear)) {
        $graduationYearErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['highSchool'])) {
        $highSchoolErr = "High School Required";
    } else {
        $highSchool = check_input($_POST['highSchool']);
    }

    $schoolGrad = check_input($_POST['schoolGrad']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $schoolGrad)) {
        $schoolGradErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $highestUnivDegree = check_input($_POST['highestUnivDegree']);

    $otherHighEdu = check_input($_POST['otherHighEdu']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $otherHighEdu)) {
        $otherHighEduErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $research = check_input($_POST['research']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $research)) {
        $researchErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $educationYear = check_input($_POST['educationYear']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $educationYear)) {
        $educationYearErr = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $educationGrad = check_input($_POST['educationGrad']);

    if (empty($_POST['lang1'])) {
        $lang1Err = "Language 1 Required";
    } else {
        $lang1 = check_input($_POST['lang1']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lang1degree'])) {
        $lang1degreeErr = "High School Required";
    } else {
        $lang1degree = check_input($_POST['lang1degree']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lang2'])) {
        $lang2Err = "High School Required";
    } else {
        $lang2 = check_input($_POST['lang2']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lang2degree'])) {
        $lang2degreeErr = "High School Required";
    } else {
        $lang2degree = check_input($_POST['lang2degree']);
    }

    $lang3 = check_input($_POST['lang3']);
    $lang3degree = check_input($_POST['lang3degree']);

    $lang4 = check_input($_POST['lang4']);

    $putData = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO hired_education_info(id, uid, first_university_degree, university, faculty,
    other_faculty, major, other_major, university_grad, grad_project, graduation_year, high_school_degree,
    other_high_school_degree, highest_university_degree, other_highest_university_degree, field_of_research,
    gs_graduation_year, gs_grade, lang1, lang1degree, lang2, lang2degree, lang3, lang3degree, other_lang)
    VALUE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $putData->bind_param('iisssssssssssssssssssssss', $id, $uid, $FirstUniversityDegree, $university, $faculty,
        $otherFaculty, $major, $otherMajor, $univGrad, $gradProject, $graduationYear, $highSchool, $schoolGrad,
        $highestUnivDegree, $otherHighEdu, $research, $educationYear, $educationGrad, $lang1, $lang1degreeErr,
        $lang2, $lang2degree, $lang3, $lang3degree, $lang4);

    $putData->execute();
}
```

now my request is:
How to redirect the user after executing the query like this?

```
if($putData->execute()){
header("Location:?pid=5&m=p");
}else{
header("Location:?pid=5&m=f");
}
```

**Update**
I update the last part of the code to

```
if ($putData->execute()) {
        $valid = true;
    } else {
        $valid = false;
    }
    if ($valid == true) {
        header("Location=?pid=4&pp=2&pps=education&m=g");
    }elseif($valid==false){
        header("Location=?pid=4&pp=2&pps=education&m=f");
    }
```

now what happens when I try this code above it stay on the same page without redirect the users.

**Update**

it was the header formatting `header("Location=?pid=4&pp=2&pps=education&m=g");` should be `header("Location:?pid=4&pp=2&pps=education&m=g");`
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check if the user filled all the required input fields, else it will execute the header.

i found this [test if the user has filled all the inputs in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007687/test-if-the-user-has-filled-all-the-inputs-in-a-form)

hope it helps.